# Where can I find examples of demoscene-like pixel art effects?

Tags: graphic-effects, special-effects

I will keep this simple. The question pretty much sums up what I am looking for. Where are some locations for 2D effects. Specifically ones like those used in old Amiga demos. They do not need to have source code. I am just looking for inspiration to code and replicate some of the effects.

It would be nice to have a list of links to images and examples as opposed to downloading old demos and running them through an emulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [The Art of Demomaking](https://www.flipcode.com/archives/The_Art_of_Demomaking-Issue_01_Prologue.shtml) from the old flipcode archives might be a good start. [The whole site](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/articles.shtml) has a lot of stuff, but is mostly PC centric although pre 3D hardware.
- These'll blow your mind nicely: [Old School Color Cycling with HTML5](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304015704/http://www.effectgames.com/effect/article.psp.html/joe/Old_School_Color_Cycling_with_HTML5#_section_1_6)
- [Hornet archives](https://ftp.scene.org/mirrors/hornet/code/) have the biggest collection of oldschool sources and docs in the internets (mostly from PC though). You can access it through the `ftp` protocol if you want.
- [Pouet](https://www.pouet.net), among other goodies, has a metric ton of links to youtube vids, so you don't have to use any emulator
- [AmigaDemos.org](http://amigademos.altervista.org/index.htm) would be similar to Pouet.